# How to get the mesh of an object in RealityKit from Experience.reality file

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit

I am loading a scene from a `.reality` file, and I want to give it an accurate collision because at the moment it is not accurate.
So in order to do that, I want to generate a convex of the mesh of my object.
The issue I'm having is that I don't find a way to retrieve the mesh of my object from a scene, tried to cast it to `ModelEntity` in order to get its `.model` property, but the casting fails for some reason.

```
guard let object = scene.objectName else { return } /// object is `Entity`
let model = object as! ModelEntity // Fails
```

This is my code, I am looking for what should go into the `generateConvex(from: ?)` function:

```
Experience.loadSceneAsync { result in
  switch result:
  case let .success(scene):
      guard let object = scene.objectName else { return }
      object.components[CollisionComponent.self] = CollisionComponent(
                        shapes: [ShapeResource.generateConvex(from: ...)]
                    )
  case let .failure(error):
      ...
}
```

One approach I can think of, is to load the model separately as `ModelEntity`, then get its mesh, but it seems off.

How can I retrieve the mesh/geometry of my object from a scene, is there no way to get the mesh of an Entity class? is there something I should do in RealityComposer that I haven't done, and that's why the casting fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the model mesh transform is always the one the designer gave when creating it. Even though the `Entity`'s transform might change, the mesh transform remains intact. Furthermore the `bounds` property on the `mesh` is a `get` only property, which means that it cannot be changed dynamically.

That said, there is a way to get a resized mesh in order to create a `CollisionComponent` with the correct size, by recreating the mesh, with the correct transform.

The steps are the following:

```
func collisionShape(modelName: String, onEntity entity: Entity) -> ShapeResource {
    // 1. Retrieve the current visual bounds of the entity.
    let entityBoundingBox = entity.visualBounds(relativeTo: nil)
        
    // 2. Locate the model entity among the children through the `ModelEntity`'s name,
    // although you can also do it recursively.
    let modelEntity = entity.findEntity(named: modelName) as! ModelEntity
    // 3. Grab the mesh.
    let modelEntityMesh = modelEntity.model!.mesh
        
    // 4. Calculate the scale on each dimension
    let xScale = entityBoundingBox.extents.x / modelEntityMesh.bounds.extents.x
    let yScale = entityBoundingBox.extents.y / modelEntityMesh.bounds.extents.y
    let zScale = entityBoundingBox.extents.z / modelEntityMesh.bounds.extents.z
        
    // 5. Create a new transform with the new scale.
    let scaledTransform = float4x4(scale: .init(x: xScale, y: yScale, z: zScale))
        
    // 6. Grab the models unchanged.
    let meshModels = modelEntityMesh.contents.models
    // 7. Grab the instances and replace their transform with the scaled one
    let transformedInstances = modelEntityMesh.contents.instances
        .map { instance -> MeshResource.Instance in
            var instance = instance
            instance.transform = scaledTransform
            return instance
        }
        
    // 8. Create the new `MeshResource.Contents`.
    var transformedContents = MeshResource.Contents()
    transformedContents.models = meshModels
    transformedContents.instances = MeshInstanceCollection(transformedInstances)
        
    // 9. Generate a new transformed `MeshResource` from the transformed contents.
    let transformedMesh = try! MeshResource.generate(from: transformedContents)
    let resource = ShapeResource.generateConvex(from: transformedMesh)
        
    return resource
}
```

With that you can now create the `CollisionComponent` you need:

```
let shapeResource = collisionShape(
    modelName: "MyModelName", 
    onEntity: MyRealityFileEntity
)
let collision = CollisionComponent(shapes: [shapeResource])
```

I use these convenience functions to get the scaled `float4x4` for the transform:

```
extension float4x4 {

  init(scale factor: Float) {
        self.init(scale: SIMD3<Float>(repeating: factor))
    }
    
  init(scale vector: SIMD3<Float>) {
        self.init(SIMD4<Float>(vector.x, 0, 0, 0),
                  SIMD4<Float>(0, vector.y, 0, 0),
                  SIMD4<Float>(0, 0, vector.z, 0),
                  SIMD4<Float>(0, 0, 0, 1))
    }
}
```